# How to disable/block user from entering command on serial terminal in embedded linux

Tags: linux, embedded, serial-port

I am working on a small Embedded project and I would like to disable user from entering commands or navigating through embedded device file system through serial port. I want to set serial port read only mode so that user can do noting.

Comment: run "getty" on serial port?

Comment: getty is not supported by embedded device linux OS. Is there any other way to control serial port on device like changes is device drivers etc..

Comment: I guess you could always hack the serial driver such that it doesn't accept input (just accept the character, but never "wake" the read thread).

Comment: Did you try giving user a read-only permission on ttyXX Example # chown user1 /dev/ttyS0 and 
# chmod 0600 /dev/ttyS0

Comment: *"I want to set serial port read only mode so that user can do noting"* -- Permissions are from the perspective of the target system (and not from the user's perspective).  So you probably mean that the serial port (console) should only have *write permission* (so that console message can be displayed).  It's *read* permission that you want to disable.

Comment: All you have to do is inhibit login on the console (and any other serial ports) or use somekind of restrictive shell. Linux has so many security features that there should be no reason to resort to kludging kernel drivers to inhibit user input. The exact means of preventing login on the console would depend on what style of initialization code your system uses, e.g. System V or BusyBox?

Comment: what init system are you using?  How is the console started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to get a login to be limited, use the restricted shell instead of a normal one.

Change the /etc/passwd for the user to point to a restricted shell, not a regular one.

This is more difficult using if you are using busybox (not in busybox by default).

If you have really unusual requirements (and it seems you do), write your own simple shell instead. Look at the busybox sources for inspiration?

It's just a loop that reads stdin, parses and execute the "command" that matches the  user input. If you want to be grandiose; a read-evaluate-print loop (REPL).

If you don't provide a command for changing the working directory, then there is not one.

So maybe your shell might have just three commands: show status, help and reboot.
(I'd recommend to add some sort of upgrade firmware command... although this starts being real work very quickly)

I've had occasion to write a mini-shell for an embedded system that was special purpose.